# Conditional regex length based on the first character

Tags: php, regex

There is a string with numbers I need to validate with PHP preg_match.
If it starts with 10 or 20 or 30, I need 7 more numbers after the inital 2, but in any other cases I need 8 numbers only and don't care what are the lead characters.
The first part is the simple one
`/^(1|2|3)0\d{7}$`

But how can I add an ELSE part? There I need a simple

`^\d{8}$`

I need to match these examples:

101234567

201234567

12345678

33445566

Comment: `^([1-3]0\d{7}|\d{8})$`

Comment: Tried that but it matches 10123456 wich starts 10 and has only 6 more numbers

Comment: Then `^([1-3]0\d{7}|(?![1-3]0)\d{8})$`

Comment: great, this is what I needed, thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
^(?:[1-3]0\d{7}|(?![1-3]0)\d{8})$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k2u5wF/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `[1-3]0\d{7}` - `1`, `2` or `3`, then `0` and any 7 digits
  - `|` - or
  - `(?![1-3]0)\d{8}` - no `10`, `20` or `30` immediately at the start of the string are allowed, then any 8 digits are matched
- `)` - end of the group
- `$` - end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative using `(?(?=regex)then|else)` aka [conditionals](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html):

```
^(?(?=[1-3]0)[1-3]0\d{7}|\d{8})$
```

It literally says: if `[1-3]0` is right at the start, match `[1-3]0\d{7}`, else match `\d{8}`.

**Demo: https://regex101.com/r/LXoHyk/1** (examples shamelessly taken from Wiktor's answer)